# Does it exist some kind of numpy array locking mechanism?

Tags: python, numpy, locking

Recently I work on a project, in which I run two module parallel but within separate interpreter. I want to establish an IPC via numpy memmap.

The main part of IPC works well, but I'd like to exchange some status information between processes too, which needs synchronization. So I want to lock numpy memmaps from the other modules while a certain process access it.

I did it via pickle + lockfile, but the pickling is a bottleneck, so I want it to speed up the process via direct memory IPC i.e. with numpy.memmap. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please post the code?